# How to provide auto logout at a specific time everyday in android app?

Tags: android

My application has a login facility where the session of the logged in user is maintained by storing boolean value in the shared preference.

I want the app to logout automatically at 12:00 in the night,irrespective if the device is idle or not.So that next time the user opens the application he gets the login page and the timer is set for autologout the next night.
How do i achieve this?? Where can i set the timer for auto logout everyday??

Please help! Thanks in Advance

Comment: for this u have to create services or set alarmpending intent and and in this make your prefrences false

Answer (score 1):

You can auto logout your session using the AlarmManager class. Here is the method you should call after the login.

```
private void callAutoLogout() {
    Intent alaramIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BootCompletedIntentReceiver.class);
    alaramIntent.setAction("LogOutAction");
    Log.e("MethodCall","AutoLogOutCall");
    alaramIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alaramIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Log.e("Logout", "Auto Logout set at..!" + calendar.getTime());
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

Then the BootCompletedIntentReceiver broadcast receiver will be triggered at 19.59. You can write Your action in Broadcast receiver.

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if("LogOutAction".equals(intent.getAction())){

            Log.e("LogOutAuto", intent.getAction());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Logout Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Do your action
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it by using AlarmManager, all you need to do is to create an repeated alarm which will always trigger just moment before midnight,

just follow this,

1. create an broadcast receiver, register to receive an intent with action say ACTION_CLEAR_SESSION
2. register an pending intent of type boradcast, targetting your receiver with alarm manager
3. set the repeat mode as daily, and set the trigger time just before midnight
4. once your receive the boradcast, clear your session.

[here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) is link just go throuh it for details

Else, simply reset everything whenever your app is opened after midnight..

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to do the logout at exactly 12:00 in the night. When the app gets opened just check if 12 o'clock has passed and trigger the logout then and go to the login activity. This is much easier to implement and to test.

Comment: But don't u think i will have to put this check in every activity of my application?? Because the user can be on any activity if he has pressed the home button of the device.

Comment: That's true, you could do that in a parent Activity from which every other Activity inherits. Or you could do the check before critical method calls.